# Can someone help me with comparing arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

The program I'm creating needs to be built without built-in Java library methods like in the Arrays class.

```
public static boolean areIdentical ( int[] data, int[] table )
{
    int pos = 0;
    
    if( !(data.length == table.length) )
        return false;
    else 
        while(pos < data.length) {
        if(data[pos]==table[pos]) {
            return true;
            }
            else{
                break;  
            }
    }
return false;
}
```

This is what I have so far and it works for the most part; however it doesn't work when one or both arrays are null, or when the arrays are different.

Comment: I don't think you want to have `return true;` inside the loop, because if one matching integer is found, you still need to check the rest of the array.  It seems to me that `return false;` should be somewhere inside the loop, and `return true;` should be at the bottom.

Comment: I think that `if(data.length != table.length )` is easier to read than `if( !(data.length == table.length) )`

Comment: @coder1234 People have gone to effort to answer your question.  Please accept an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle null arrays, you can add a null check at the beginning of the method. If either of the arrays is null, you can return false. To handle cases when the arrays are different, you can keep track of a boolean variable and set it to false if there is any mismatch in the values at corresponding indices. Then, return the boolean variable after the loop.

```
public static boolean areIdentical(int[] data, int[] table) {
    if (data == null || table == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (data.length != table.length) {
        return false;
    }

    boolean identical = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] != table[i]) {
            identical = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return identical;
}
```

Comment: If both arrays are null, one might want to consider them equal instead of inequal.

Comment: I would reject any null array by using `Objects.requireNonNull(…)`.

Comment: There's no need for the `identical` variable or the `break`. just return `false` in the `if` and `true` at the end of the method.

Answer (score 1):

Your check is backwards. You can't return true on the first matching pair. This means, if the first elements are the same, but the rest are different, you ignore the rest.

You need to scan through the elements, aborting early and returning **false** on the first **non-matching** pair. You can only return `true` when you have reached the end of the loop and have no non-matching pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return when elements are equal, or you will always return `true` if the first elements are equal.

Then you need to check for `null` explicitly, if you want to allow `null` values.

You can simplify the `if (!(a == b))` to `if (a != b)`. You should always use curly braces in `if` and `else`, it makes the code easier to read and when you later add more statements, you need them anyway.
Finally, if you already return in the `if` for the array length check, you don't need an `else` when the arrays have the same length.

```java
public static boolean areIdentical (int[] data, int[] table) {
    if (data == null && table == null) {
        return true;
    }
    if (data == null || table == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (data.length != table.length) {
        return false;
    }
    
    int pos = 0;
    while (pos < data.length) {
        if (data[pos] != table[pos]) {
            return false;
        }
        pos++;
    }
    return true;
}
```